# External Webcam just stopped working without any reason

Tags: kernel, webcam

I am using Dell Latitude 5420, **Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS x86_64, Kernel: 5.14.0-1038-oem, Intel i7-1165G7**.

In the beginning when I got the webcam(Logitech C505) (3 days back) I was not able to use it, no logs in `dmesg`. Upon searching for the solution I arrived at

```
sudo apt-get install cheese build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

and after that it worked like charm.

Today it was just not working. I checked if any updates made this change but no, it just isn't working. (it was at Kernel 5.14.0-1038-oem when I last used it without any issues)

Today I am not able to see any logs in `dmesg` or `lsblk`